# How to add leading zeros to a field in excel

Tags: excel

I have a currency amount that for example is 11.20

I need it to be 11 characters not including the '(see below), with leading 0's to fill the characters.

I need 4 characters to the right of the decimal, and it needs to have a ' on the end so my end value needs to be:

00000112000'

I have tried multiple formulas and for some reason can't figure this out as basic as it might seem.

Comment: Right-click the cell that contains `11.20` -> Format Cells -> Custom -> Type in the field `0000000.0000'` -> OK

Comment: If you need this to be the result of a formula for some reason, can use the `TEXT` function: `=TEXT(A1,"0000000.0000'")`

Comment: And if you actually don't need the decimal, then you can either remove it with a `SUBSTITUTE`, or multiply the value by 10,000

Comment: Thanks Tiger. How would I add the x 10000 to the formula?

Comment: `=TEXT(A1*10000,"00000000000'")`

Comment: Note however that the result will be a *string* value and not a true number. This means that trying to perform number calculations on the result will likely give errors, or incorrect answers.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 3):

Go to "Format Cells". In "Number" tab select "Custom". And type in "Type" as many zeros as you need:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.